# Creating space in looping

Tags: r

How to create empty space in a for loop to save the output if I don't know the number of looping that will be iterated and save the result in a certain file format in a folder?

```
data<- 
for(i in 1:9){
for(j in 1:5){
   for (b in 1:5){
  for (f in 1:(max(data[,'colum']))) {
model.fit<-lm(y~x)
#again I want to pull out the coefficients and all necessessary values and put them somewhere as matrix or anything else..
I also want to add another model and put the results together
      }
   }
 }
}
write.table ()
```

Comment: Please post what you want your final output to look like and some sample data in a usable format.  Use `dput(YOURDATA)` and post the results.  If they're really long, use `dput(head(YOURDATA))`.

Comment: you could just create an empty list `list = list()` and then initialize an auxiliar variable which you use as a placeholder and update each iteration, so `aux=1 ; for ( ... list[aux] = results ; aux = aux + 1`

Comment: Agree with @boski.  You don't even need the auxiliary variable. `results <- list(); for ... results <- c(results, list(current_value)) ...`

Comment: @BenBolker Yep but I believe my method is faster :)

Comment: Thanks, @boski, can you please give me a little elaboration on your method?

Comment: I'm mildly skeptical -- in either case you have to append a new element to the list -- but I'm not going to bother benchmarking to check ...

Comment: @BenBolker, thanks so much, is there a way to put it in function form or vectorized form as it seems that so many nested loops are not recommendable.

Comment: I don't think nested loops are actually a problem in this case.  `lm()` can't easily be vectorized.  If performance is extremely important (e.g. you have millions of rows and/or columns in your data set), there are some options such as the `fastlm` package, but it's not clear you need this. See section 4 of https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf ...

Comment: @BenBolker thanks for this important info and I want you to assist me on how to pull out all the coefficients and other values of those model using the codes and put in the folder (in text format) using write.table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can initialize a `list` and an auxiliary position variable `aux`. For your case, something similar to this:

```
mylist = list()
aux = 1

for(i in 1:9){
    for(j in 1:5){
       for (b in 1:5){
          for (f in 1:(max(data[,'colum']))) {
              mylist[[aux]]<-lm(y~x)
              aux = aux + 1
          }
       }
    }
}
write.table ()
```

In each iteration, the model is added to your list and the auxiliary variable is updated by one.

**Edit**
In case you want to add two models per iteration you can do:

```
mylist = list()
aux = 1

for(i in 1:9){
    for(j in 1:5){
       for (b in 1:5){
          for (f in 1:(max(data[,'colum']))) {
              mylist[[aux]]<-lm(y~x)
              aux = aux + 1
              mylist[[aux]] <- lm2(y~x)
              aux = aux + 1
          }
       }
    }
}
write.table ()
```

This way, all **odd** numbers will have `model.fit` and the **even** numbers `model.fit1`.
Another alternative is to use nested lists: for each step, a sublist containing `model.fit` and `model.fit1` can be created as follows:

```
mylist = list()
aux = 1

for(i in 1:9){
    for(j in 1:5){
       for (b in 1:5){
          for (f in 1:(max(data[,'colum']))) {
              mylist[[aux]]<-list(lm(y~x),lm2(y~x))
              aux = aux + 1
          }
       }
    }
}
write.table ()
```

Then, for each step you can access `model.fit` by doing `mylist[[aux]][[1]]` and `model.fit1` by doing `mylist[[aux]][[2]]`.

Comment: thank you so much and if I add another model next to model.fit in the loop, like model.fit1, how can I progress in getting the result together with model.fit?

Comment: not really sure what you mean by "getting the result together with model fit". I put up some options on my answer but please specify more by editing the question if these do not work.

Comment: you got what exactly I meant..Give you the usual thanks in StackOverflow.

Comment: please to be sure, just assist me on how to put those result using write.table at the end in my hard disk folder. Just the main syntax using the one you have used...

Comment: I would also be happy if you hint me how to write the above code in function or vectorized form.